# Jinja2 - Is it possible to have a string value + a varible in a inline if/else?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm concatenating some strings to build a iso file name with variables for the version and the update. My problem is with the update, because either there is an update version so the file will contain `UpdateX` where x is the number of the update, or it's the initial version and there is no update reference in the name.

Sample of iso names:

- VMware-ESXi-6.7.0-Update2-HPE.iso
- VMware-ESXi-6.7.0-Update1-HPE.iso
- VMware-ESXi-6.7.0-HPE.iso

So, with the normal '`{% if <cond> %}`…`{% else %}`…`{% endif %}`' I know how to do it:

```
esxi_iso: "{% if update %}\
             VMware-ESXi-{{ version }}-'Update-{{ update }}-HPE.iso\
           {% else %}\
             VMware-ESXi-{{ version }}-HPE.iso\
           {% endif %}"
```

This works.
But I want to keep that on one line. 
And I don't know how to provide the `Update-{{ update }}` as value in a inline if…

Of course the following attempt through me an templating error.

```
esxi_iso: "VMware-ESXi-{{ version }}-{{ 'Update-{{ update }}' if update else '' }}HPE.iso"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline if else is a thing in Jinja2.

```
VMware-ESXi-{{ version }}-{{ 'Update-' + update|string if update else '' }}HPE.iso
```

Or use `format` filter.

```
VMware-ESXi-{{ version }}-{{ 'Update-%s'|format(update) if update else '' }}HPE.iso
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I got the following error message: `'template error while templating string: expected token ''end of print statement'', got ''string''`.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited to correct the mistake, and actually tested the template this time.

Comment: The first one was initially complaining about  concatenate `str` and `int` but was working once I added the string filter. So both work like a charm. Thanks!